# Draw over website effect with HTML5 and Canvas

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, canvas

I'm looking for a "draw over website effect". Basically a click of a pen icon and an overlay will be put onto the screen upon which the user can draw. So far I'm having trouble with the code for two reasons:

1) It's complicated to start adding colours, erasers and sizes

2) The canvas will not accept percentage widths, so I can't overlay the whole website

I've looked at http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/ and http://cool-php-tutorials.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/simple-html5-drawing-app-with-saving.html

Both of these sites are good, but I was wondering if anyone knows of a pre-built solution to achieve this, or of a way to overcome the problems (mainly the second).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: selection on site will not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The canvas will not accept percentage widths, so I can't overlay the whole website

Just calculate document width and height with `$(document).width()` and `$(document).height()` and assign this values to the canvas.

Comment: For some reason I couldn't get this to work, I couldn't get it to go bigger than the viewport. That would be a seperate question however, there's a load of code lol. Thanks :)

Comment: It should work: Check http://jsbin.com/upikiv/2, click on the pen and check the numbers and the red border drawn on the canvas.